# How to change "Master Password" of KeePass2 Database?

Tags: windows-7, passwords

I am wondering how to change the main database password that contains all my passwords in *KeePass2*. Figure 1 below shows what I am trying to describe. I think I could do this without help but wanted someone to explain it to me before I tried it and potentially lost all my passwords. I looked on the website for *KeePass2* and did not see any tutorials on this. This is surprising to me as it implies that everyone will keep the same database password for as long as they use the *KeePass2* software. Maybe this is not a big mystery for other people though as it is for me.

[image]

*Figure 1*:How to change this password

Comment: My post was edited in a way I do not appreciate. :/

Comment: Last paragraph of your question off topic here.  It may cause your question to be down voted or even closed.

Comment: I think it is an important comment on the current state of technology. The last paragraph does mention passwords and this post is all about passwords. :)

Comment: You may feel it important,  but still off topic here.  It's primary opinion based, too broad... (see help center to learn what's on topic here). The very typical question which can be discussed in a forum,  but can't receive a good answer here. What reaction do you expect on it?

Comment: I guess I wanted to spark a debate on passwords when people go home and talk about stuff. I also wanted to change the use of passwords by making them obsolete, relics of a dumber time. These are all high flying dreams though...

Comment: over editing my post does not help anyone

Comment: Why do you think so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After opening the database go to File > Change Master Key, and there you can change it.

[image: KeePass2 File Menu]

Comment: I will try this later. Thank-you for the quick answer. :)